# Use of cell.value vs cell.internal_value for openpyxl's iter_rows() method

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working on a piece of code from two computers.  I use openpyxl to read data from an excel sheet, with `load_workbook` keyword arguments `data_only=True` and `use_iterators=True`.  Depending on which computer I'm using, I need to use either `cell.value` or `cell.internal_value`.  Why is this the case?

Here's the read:

```
raw_rows = []
for row in openpyxl_sheet.iter_rows():
    #  raw_rows.append([cell.internal_value for cell in row])
    raw_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])
return raw_rows
```

As a temporary workaround, I've been swapping between lines 3 and 4.

On one computer, `cell.value` gives me the cell data and `cell.internal_value` throws the following attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'RawCell' object has no attribute 'value'
```

On the other computer, both `cell.value` and `cell.internal_value` give me data, but only `cell.internal_value` gives the correct data.

From what I can tell from reading other questions on the site, I should be using `cell.internal_value` for both.  I've used Anaconda to install openpyxl on both computers.

Comment: Prior to openpyxl version 2, the API for the different modes was different. :-/ This is no longer the case. When working on different machines it's always worth trying to use the same versions of the libraries on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a different version of openpyxl on each computer.  I had thought they'd be the same since I used Anaconda to install each.  The issues was fixed with `conda update openpyxl`.  After updating, using `cell.value` works for both.

I'll leave the question up in case another user can identify a solution that doesn't assume that you're able to change the version of openpyxl.